# Disable FN keys in Mac Lion

Tags: macos

Prior to Lion, I can go to Keyboard and there is a nice little checkbox, then I can get my F1-F12 key back.

How do I do this in Lion ?

Answer (score 8):

**System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard**

[image]

Comment: Is this screens short from Lion ?

Comment: @thinkanotherone Yes.

Comment: Crazy...:( Maybe because I am using a Microsoft keyboard...

Comment: @thinkanotherone That makes sense because this functionally is needed for Apple's keyboards as the default mapping is for media keys. What can you do with your function keys? You can see what keys you press using the **Keyboard & Character Viewer** in **System Prefs > Language & Text**.

Comment: @thinkanotherone You might also give this [keyboard remapping software](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html) a try.